# remove stopwords using for loop in python

Tags: python, loops, stop-words

I am recently studying python loop, and I want to try if I can use for loop to remove stop words and punctuation.

However, my code doesn't work and it shows punctuation is not defined. (the stopwords can be removed thanks to the comment)

I know it can be achieved using list comprehension and there are a lot of answers in StackOverflow, but I want to know how would it be achieved using for loop.

The code I used for practice is below:

```
texts = 'I love python, From John'

stopword = ['i', 'from']
punctuations = ','

texts = texts.split()

empty_list = []
    
for text in texts:
    text = text.lower()
    if text not in stopword and punctuation not in punctuations:
        empty_list.append(text)
        print(empty_list)
```

the expected output would be `love python John`

thanks for the help

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: You are printing `empty_string` not `empty_list`

Comment: and your stopword = ['i, from'] has one entry. Are you missing quotes ?

Comment: `stopword = ['i, from']` should be `stopword = ['i', 'from']` and `empty_string` should be `empty_list`.

Comment: I updated my question with the punctuation problem, do I have to do a separate loop or can be achieved within this loop, thanks

Comment: your stopword has still only one item. and punctuations is not a list but only a string, so you will never have more than one puntuation?

Comment: this is just an example I am practising to be familiar with remove words and punctuation, I know the real-world problem is a lot more difficult than this.

Comment: Well, if later on you change the type from a string to a list you will have to redo your code. That's why I'm asking. your stopword continues to be only one element btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Punctuation can be attached to words, so user replace.

Then split the text into words, convert them to lower and for each word check if it exist in stopwords

```
text = 'I love python, From John'
stopwords = ['i', 'from']
punctuations = [',']

# first remove punctuations
for p in punctuations:
    text = text.replace(p, "")
# then split the text string and for each element check if it exist in stopwords

result = []
for word in text.split():
    if word.lower() not in stopwords:
        result.append(word)

# join into string
result = " ".join(result)
```

Result:

```
'love python John'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it as a list comprehension and avoid a for loop like this:

```
texts = 'I love python, from John'
stopword = ['I', 'from']
punctuations = [',']

[word for word in texts.split(' ') if word not in stopword and word not in [',']]

//['love', 'python,', 'John']
```

Comment: I ran your code and the result is `['I', 'love', 'python,', 'From', 'John']`  You are not conveting to lowercase, so I and From will never be captured

Comment: That will be because of the upper case `I`.  i have edited

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks. I know list comprehension is a more simple version, but I just wanted to try practising using for loop to familiarise myself with it. This is a very good answer and thanks for the comment.

Comment: changing the original sentence is cheating. In real life you won't have control over the input sentence. Also your are hardcoding the punctuation in your list comprehension instead of using the variable punctuations. And your code doesn't remove the comma at all, is still attached to "python,"

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating through chars with that loop.
You should use the .split() method to split the string in words (split using ' ' for example) and then you will be able to .pop() that words from the list of words created with .split().

Comment: code is better than explanations. you cannot explain the interpreter what to do, but you can with code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
import string 
texts = 'I love python, From John'
stopword = ['i, from']

text = texts.translate(str.maketrans('','',string.punctuation)).lower().split(' ')

empty_list = [word for word in text if word not in stopword]
```

I added the punctuation remover in order to get rid of ',from', 'from?' that wouldn't be seen otherwise

Answer (score 0):

So if I understood correctly your question the answer will be to use the pop instruction after you found a word which is in stopword.

The first mistake was in the stopword list, cause you have only one element there, elements need to be separated like the following example:

```
list = ['one', 'two', 'three']
```

After this mention you need also a instruction like **remove** for deleting the unwanted elements.

So the implementation will be the following:

```
texts = 'I love python, From John'

stopword = ['i', 'from']

texts = texts.split()

empty_list = []

for text in texts:
    text_original = text
    text = text.lower()
    if text not in stopword:
        empty_list.append(text_original)
        #print(empty_string)
    else:
        texts.remove(text_original)

print(texts, empty_list)
```

Hope to help you this.